# How to set env vars in 1st spring boot app to access into another app

Tags: spring-boot, environment

I am having a use case to read some specific env variable which are set at system level based on the queried to database and want to refer into another spring boot app

I am able to set it through System.setProperty("XYZ", "123") but when I refer it into another spring boot app it is returning null with System.getProperty call..

And both application is running into same container or JVM or instance...

Please, help...

Thanks,

Comment: How do they run in the same VM? Do you run it in Tomcat?

Comment: @Simon, I am running it into same container deployed on different port. I've also deployed using java commands just to check this..

Comment: What container? Docker?

Comment: @Simon, Container used to test this is embedded tomcat of spring boot and deployed into Open stack vm instance.

Comment: But then your two apps don't run in the same Java VM process and you cannot access the System Property

Comment: Yes, agree so actually looking for the alternative for this scenario is there a way because my use case is to fetch some db records and set into env vars and need to access into different app.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't use System.setProperty because this is only visible in current Java process
2. You can't use System.setEnv because this is also only visible in the current process

You could write a file that the other process is reading or you could provide a REST endpoint so that one app can call the app.

Comment: yes that is possible but want to avoid IO operations but can think of this rest endpoint based approach having said that it has its own complexity of handling error response explicitly...

Comment: Btw all the options are IO